# Crawl someone's status updates on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Is there a tool out there that will crawl one of your friend's status updates and download them to a file? I'm doing some research and it's a pain to keep hitting "older posts.."

Comment: "I'm doing some stalking" FTFY.  Jokes aside, I don't know of any way to do this now that they stopped piping this stuff to RSS but maybe there's some backdoor functionality I'm unaware of.

Comment: I suggest you elaborate a bit about what you're specifically trying to do and since Super User isn't about websites, it should be more general regarding crawling any site.

Comment: I would like to collect a friend's status updates for a period of time. Specifically, from the present back one year, I want to collect the text of the status updates from his profile.

Comment: PS - Stalking would seem to be easier done with some other method. This is data collection.

Comment: Do you have any experience with scripting? I don't expect there to be clear cut tools for crawling Facebook (nor that it's allowed)

Comment: Facebook has an official API for retrieving user data. Any other scraping would be considered a violation of their terms of use. See https://developers.facebook.com/ for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the questions on StackOverflow about the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/).
Your solution for instance, may involve something like [wget](http://www.google.com/search?q=wget) and a URL of the form (or similar): https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME_HERE/feed.

E.g.: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed

In fact by examining the bottom previous/next links from this page, I can see that adding a query similar to `?limit=25` and perhaps even `&since=2011-02-09T04` may be just what you need.

E.g.: https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed?limit=100

Answer (score 3):

Try [fb-crawl](https://code.google.com/p/fb-crawl/).

It's a Perl script that will insert wall posts, user information, and friends into a MySQL database. From there you can sift through the data using MySQL `SELECT` statements. It doesn't make any API calls, so if you can see it on Facebook, fb-crawl can get it.